# How could I prevent an UIAlertview window appearing in my app

Tags: ios, uialertview, vlc

I'm using MobileVLCKit in my IOS program to open video streams via internet, but sometimes the app cannot connect to internet or occur an error while opening the video, it will pop up an alert view to tell the error information, but I don't want my users see these info.

I use the MobileVLCKit.framework so can't read the .m files cause beside the .h file all packaged in one file (like below the picture display), so I can't just modify the alert view message, but how could I prevent these alert showing and pop up an alert view of my own?

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq9Vm.png)

Comment: you have to find code where Alert box is shown.Then you can comment code for show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-compile MobileVLCKit yourself to disable these dialogs. Remove the line referencing the iOS Dialog Provider from VLCLibrary.m. That's all :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm just cannot download the source code due to the bad net access, but there's maybe no more good ways to resolve it, thanks anyway.